# Google Chrome push notification - Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, web-applications, push-notification

I am interested to enable google push notification for my web application in Chrome. I want to use Java as primary programming language. I tried to look at many examples but I didn't get caught of any information which helps me. Can anyone please let me know how to start with?

Regards,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the notification API. It is much simpler to use. To find examples of the I would direct you to Youtube with the exact same question. The Rich Notification is a very complex system, but google also but out a few videos on how to use them.